# Dealing with date and time functionality in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, date

I have a date in the database and I want to export it to DATE_TIME.civil() format like the one shown below (I am doing this to export it to a .ics calendar file)

> DTSTART:20100605T083000
>
> DTEND:20100606T083000

I have two fields in the database one called start_date and two fields start_time and end_time.

I want to add the times (start_time and end_time to the start_date) and convert it to the DATE_TIME.civil() format as shown above. I tried doing the following:

```
my_datestart = obj.start_date + obj.start_time
my_dataend = obj.start_date + obj.end_time
```

I know it's a supremely wrong syntax, but my objective is to get the date in that format.

**Edit:** The database type of start_time => time and start_date => datetime. Both in MySQL. I am using a ActiveRecord to access them

Please help me.

Comment: What format are the dates/times in the database?

Comment: start_time => time and start_date => datetime. Both in MySQL. I am using a ActiveRecord to access them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **[strftime](http://www.nullislove.com/2007/05/16/time-for-strftime/)** method of the date

```
@date=Time.now
@date.strftime("%Y%m%d %H%M%S")  ####GIVES "20100604 193059"
```